# Find the countour integral of $\int_{γ} \sqrt{z} dz$ where $γ=C(2,1)^+$ or $γ=C(1,1)^{+}$ or $γ=C(0,1)^{+}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Find the countour integral of $\int_{γ} \sqrt{z} dz$ where
>   $γ=C(2,1)^+$ or $γ=C(1,1)^{+}$ or $γ=C(0,1)^{+}$

With $\sqrt{z}$ I mean the branch with the non-positive real axis as branch cut.
With $C(a,r)^{+}$ I mean the circle with center $a$ and radius $r$, with $+$ I mean that the circle is postive orientated (counter clockwise).

My effort:

I think for $γ=C(2,1)^+$ I can just use Cauchy's theorem.
For $γ=C(1,1)^+$ I can't use that theorem, and I'm don't know how to evaluate this integral:

$\int_{0}^{2π} \sqrt{|1+e^{it} | } (1+e^{it}) ie^{it} dt$

For the last one $γ=C(0,1)^{+}$, $\sqrt{z}$ is not continuous at this curve (at $-1$), so therefore it's not defined. Right ?

Comment: Please explain for the perplexed the notation $C(m,n)^+$.

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry, my books use this all the time, and I didn't know that it was not standard. I edited my question.